# Obtener NameSpace de XML con FETCH API JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml

Estoy haciendo una consulta a un archivo XML con FETCH API, pero las consultas que estoy haciendo son muy largas, pero no comprendo muy bien como hacer obtener los datos de los NameSpace del archivo. Su apoyo para poder obtener la info antes mencionada y corregir por que se muestran entre nodos un text.

Este es mi codigo JavaScript:

```
const cargaBtn = document.querySelector('#botonX');
cargaBtn.addEventListener('click',obtenerDatos);

function obtenerDatos(){
    const docto = "ejemplo1.xml";

    fetch(docto)
        .then(respuesta => {
            return respuesta.text();
        })
        .then(xmlString =>{

            let parser = new DOMParser();
            let xmlDOM = parser.parseFromString(xmlString,"text/xml");
            let comprobante = xmlDOM.querySelectorAll('Comprobante');

            //EMISOR
            console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes']);
            console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][1].attributes);
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][0].nextElementSibling.attributes);
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][0].nextElementSibling.attributes[0]);
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][0].nextElementSibling.attributes[1]);
                        
                        //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][0].nextElementSibling.attributes['Rfc'].value);



            //RECEPTOR
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][1].attributes);
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][1].attributes[0]);
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][1].attributes[1]);
            
            
            
            //CONCEPTOS
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][2].childNodes);
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][2].childNodes[0]);
            
            

            //IMPUESTOS
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][3].attributes);
            

            //COMPLEMENTO
            //console.log(comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement['childNodes'][4].firstChild.attributes);
            

            
        })
        .catch( error =>{
            console.log(error);
        })


}
```

Este es el archivo ejemplo1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfdi:Comprobante
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4"
    xmlns:cartaporte20="http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/4 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/4/cfdv40.xsd http://www.sat.gob.mx/CartaPorte20 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/CartaPorte/CartaPorte20.xsd" Version="4.0" Folio="113" Fecha="2023-08-17T13:48:55"  FormaPago="99" NoCertificado="00001000000510966981" CondicionesDePago="0" SubTotal="42000.00" Moneda="MXN" TipoCambio="1" Total="47034.75" TipoDeComprobante="I" Exportacion="01" MetodoPago="PPD" LugarExpedicion="43806">
    <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="XEXX010101000" Nombre="PERSONA FISICA" RegimenFiscal="626"/>
    <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="XAXX010101000" Nombre="PERSONA FISICA 2" DomicilioFiscalReceptor="31500" RegimenFiscalReceptor="622" UsoCFDI="G03"/>
    <cfdi:Conceptos>
        <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="78101802" NoIdentificacion="1" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Unidad="Unidad de servicio" Descripcion="Viaje de manzana Salida de CD guerrero chihuahua a la central de abastos Iztapalapa México bodega L 112 Fecha carga 16-08-23 Hora de salida. 7 pm" ValorUnitario="42.00" Importe="42.00" ObjetoImp="02">
            <cfdi:Impuestos>
                <cfdi:Traslados>
                    <cfdi:Traslado Base="42.000000" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="6.720000"/>
                </cfdi:Traslados>
                <cfdi:Retenciones>
                    <cfdi:Retencion Base="42.000000" Impuesto="001" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.000125" Importe="5.250000"/>
                    <cfdi:Retencion Base="42000.000000" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.040000" Importe="1.680000"/>
                </cfdi:Retenciones>
            </cfdi:Impuestos>
        </cfdi:Concepto>
    </cfdi:Conceptos>
    <cfdi:Impuestos TotalImpuestosRetenidos="1.68525" TotalImpuestosTrasladados="6.7200">
        <cfdi:Retenciones>
            <cfdi:Retencion Impuesto="001" Importe="5.25"/>
            <cfdi:Retencion Impuesto="002" Importe="1.68"/>
        </cfdi:Retenciones>
        <cfdi:Traslados>
            <cfdi:Traslado Base="42.00" Impuesto="002" TipoFactor="Tasa" TasaOCuota="0.160000" Importe="6.72"/>
        </cfdi:Traslados>
    </cfdi:Impuestos>
    <cfdi:Complemento>
        <tfd:TimbreFiscalDigital
            xmlns:tfd="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/TimbreFiscalDigital http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/TimbreFiscalDigital/TimbreFiscalDigitalv11.xsd" Version="1.1" UUID="B5FE9B1B-707C-4619-B954-527DEF6B7464" FechaTimbrado="2023-08-17T13:48:58"/>
            <cartaporte20:CartaPorte Version="2.0" TranspInternac="No" TotalDistRec="1500.00">
                <cartaporte20:Ubicaciones>
                    <cartaporte20:Ubicacion TipoUbicacion="Origen" IDUbicacion="OR000000" RFCRemitenteDestinatario="XEXX010101000" NombreRemitenteDestinatario="AGROPECUARIA" FechaHoraSalidaLlegada="2023-08-16T19:00:00">
                        <cartaporte20:Domicilio Calle="ALDAMA ENTRE 9NA Y 11VA" Colonia="0104" Municipio="017" Pais="MEX" CodigoPostal="00001"/>
                    </cartaporte20:Ubicacion>
                    <cartaporte20:Ubicacion TipoUbicacion="Destino" IDUbicacion="DE000000" RFCRemitenteDestinatario="XEXX010101000" NombreRemitenteDestinatario="AGROPECUARIA" FechaHoraSalidaLlegada="2023-08-17T13:46:00" DistanciaRecorrida="1500.00">
                        <cartaporte20:Domicilio Calle="ALDAMA ENTRE 9NA Y 11VA" Colonia="0104" Municipio="017" Pais="MEX" CodigoPostal="00001"/>
                    </cartaporte20:Ubicacion>
                </cartaporte20:Ubicaciones>
                <cartaporte20:Mercancias PesoBrutoTotal="29000.000" UnidadPeso="XBX" PesoNetoTotal="29000.000" NumTotalMercancias="1">
                    <cartaporte20:Mercancia BienesTransp="50301572" Descripcion="MANZANA ROJO DELICIUS" Cantidad="1372.000" ClaveUnidad="XBX" Unidad="CAJA" DescripEmbalaje="CAJA" PesoEnKg="29000.000" ValorMercancia="7.00" Moneda="MXN"/>
                    <cartaporte20:Autotransporte PermSCT="TPAF01" NumPermisoSCT="1329RASP29012018021001001">
                        <cartaporte20:IdentificacionVehicular ConfigVehicular="T3S2" PlacaVM="XXXXXX" AnioModeloVM="2009"/>
                        <cartaporte20:Seguros AseguraRespCivil="ANA SEGUROS" PolizaRespCivil="003713326"/>
                        <cartaporte20:Remolques>
                            <cartaporte20:Remolque SubTipoRem="CTR007" Placa="AAAAAA"/>
                        </cartaporte20:Remolques>
                    </cartaporte20:Autotransporte>
                </cartaporte20:Mercancias>
                <cartaporte20:FiguraTransporte>
                    <cartaporte20:TiposFigura TipoFigura="01" RFCFigura="XAXX010101000" NumLicencia="XX00146090" NombreFigura="JAVIER">
                        <cartaporte20:Domicilio Calle="C SAN DANIEL" Colonia="1907" Municipio="069" Pais="MEX" CodigoPostal="00001"/>
                    </cartaporte20:TiposFigura>
                </cartaporte20:FiguraTransporte>
            </cartaporte20:CartaPorte>
        </cfdi:Complemento>
    </cfdi:Comprobante>
```

Todos los demas nodos estan comentados ya que los vamos a utilizar mas a delante para dar un formato para que lo vea bien los usuario, y esto es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradesco mucho su apoyo.

Comment: Hola Juan, no termino de entender cual es el problema. ¿Que es lo que necesitas hacer y no podes?

Comment: @Marcos El primer detalle es que el archivo XML tiene NamesPace, y quisiera saber cual es la forma para obtener la info. de estos NameSpace y no escribir tanto codigo como lo tengo en este momento.
Y el segundo detalle es por que en la consola entre resultados se muestra #TEXT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No entiendo bien lo que quieres conseguir pero `childNodes` contiene todos los tipos de nodos (por ejemplo, nodos del tipo elemento pero también de text, de comentarios).

En navegadores modernos también hay `children`, que solo contiene los nodos del tipo elemento, por eso supongo que por ejemplo `comprobante[0].attributes['xmlns:cfdi'].ownerElement.children` es más lo que buscas.

No entiendo por qué no solo utilizas `comprobante[0].children`, acceder a un atributo con `attributes` para volver al elemento con `ownerElement` no parece ser más que un rodeo.